# What strategies have psychologists developed for learning to prioritize long-term.gains over short-term losses?

Tags: therapy, procrastination

What is an example of one technique, or strategy, psychologists have developed for addressing procrastination and/or impulsive behavior?

As a particulair case study, the kitchen in my home has no flooring (except some plywood)

In the construction industry, the plywood is known as "subflooring". I know about sub-flooring. I have installed sub-flooring and flooring before.

I purchased some boxes of fake marble tiles a long time ago. The unopened boxes of fake tiles have been sitting in my living room for weeks; completely untouched.

In the short-run, I hate installing flooring.

In the long-run, I would like my kitchen to have flooring.

What is one example of a strategy, or technique, studied by psycholigsts which can be repeatedly put into practice in order to increase the rate at which a person prioritizes their own long term happiness over own short-term happiness?

Comment: Welcome to psych.SE.  There are already lots of questions on this forum about motivation and procrastination - have you checked for existing solutions?  [What works for procrastination?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/23811/7001), [Treatment and strategies for procrastination for ADHD](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/23813/7001), [What's the optimal way to space out rewards in order to maximise motivation?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/10900/7001)...